# C++ - using strcmp to compare which name comes first in alphabetical order

Tags: c++, object, boolean, constants, strcmp

I'm new to C++ and trying to implement the `lessThan()` member function that compares the `Person` on the left-hand side (the `this` person) with the `Person` passed in as the parameter; a person is considered “less than” another if their name comes first in alphabetical order.

I made my function below but when I run it I get the error:

> cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int strcmp(const char*, const char*)’

Aside from that, I was wondering if I'm using the `this` keyword and `strcmp()` function correctly? Should it be `< 0`?

```
bool Person::lessThan(Person* per){
    if(strcmp(this->name, per->name) < 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've tagged this as `c` but it would appear you are using `c++` and `std::string`. In that case all you need to do is `return name < per->name;` and be done with it since `std::string` allows for that comparison and it is the preferred method. For completeness you could fix your code like this: `if(strcmp(this->name.c_str(), per->name.c_str()) < 0){` but it is best not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is return `name < per->name;` and be done with it since `<std::string>` allows for that comparison and it is the preferred method.

For completeness you could fix your code:

```
bool Person::lessThan(const Person* per) const {
  return strcmp(this->name.c_str(), per->name.c_str()) < 0;
}
```

[@Retired Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64310286/c-using-strcmp-to-compare-which-name-comes-first-in-alphabetical-order/64310718#comment113719874_64310286)